# Validar input para receber apenas números com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso que este input receba apenas números:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm " placeholder="número" maxlength="4"  type="text"  ng-model="numero.nJogo" />
```

Este eu preciso que receba apenas valores com esta formatação (20.00)

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="valor" maxlength="5" type="text"  ng-model="numero.valor" />
```

Comment: Não viu o preview antes de postar?

Comment: Você pode, como sugestão, alterar o type do seu input para number e deixar que o browser valide isso pra ti.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Esse script aceita somente **números** e "**.**" :

```
 <script>
    function somenteNumeros(num) {
        var er = /[^0-9.]/;
        er.lastIndex = 0;
        var campo = num;
        if (er.test(campo.value)) {
          campo.value = "";
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Só acrescente o evento onkeyup no seu input, dessa forma:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" maxlength="5" type="text"  ng-model="numero.valor" />
```

Comment: ficou perfeito, agora eu precisava formatar o outro campo, agradeço!

Comment: Eu sei que ja tem 3 anos, mas que server o er.lastIndex = 0? @Bia

Answer (score -3):

```
$(input).keydown((event): boolean => {
   return ('0123456789'.search(event.key) > 0);
});
```