# Input para recebimento de cpf

Tags: javascript

Olá sou novo no campo de javascript e estou com uma duvida, como eu posso pegar o valor das teclas e **bloquear** strings, caracteres especiais e **somente aceita NUMEROS** no meu campo.

Meu Código a baixo

```
<input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="377273288328">
<script>
    let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    numero.addEventListener("keypress", e=>{
        if(e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57){
           // o codigo do 0 ao 9
        }else{
       //como eu bloqueio? 
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: no `else` coloque `e.preventDefault();` para bloquear o evento padrão ao apertar a tecla

Comment: [Validar input para receber apenas números com jquery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106082/)

Comment: Guilherme Muito Obrigado resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Nem precisa de script para isso, apenas defina o tipo do campo como `number` .... `<input type="number" id="numero" placeholder="377273288328">`

Comment: Eu postei uma resposta sobre cpf que valida de acordo com a regra da Receita Federal, ou seja, somente se for um cpf válido e verdadeiro. Se lhe interessar veja em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295564/como-validar-cpf-com-m%C3%A1scara-em-javascript/295566#295566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="377273288328">
<script>
    let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
    numero.addEventListener("keypress", e=>{
        if(e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=57){
           return true;
        }else{
            e.preventDefault();// bloquea o evento padrão ao apertar a tecla
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: A sua resposta está correta, mas não responda apenas com código. Explique um pouco o que o seu código tem de diferente em relação ao da pergunta, caso contrário uma pessoa que leia a sua resposta pode não conseguir perceber de imediato.

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer só `return false` para **negar** a tecla que foi carregada.

Houve [uma discussão sobre isso recentemente aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114596/como-bloquear-determinadas-teclas-num-input-usando-javascript), embora fosse para bloquear outros caracteres.

Comment: No caso ele retorna falso mas o input ainda aceita todos os tipos de caracteres